# A Database Error Occurred in codeigniter.

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

what is this error? How do I fix it?
i use of codeigniter.

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1048

Column 'captcha_time' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `captcha` (`captcha_time`, `ip_address`, `word`) VALUES (NULL, '31.57.141.7', NULL)

Filename: /home/324/public_html/123/models/login_model.php

Line Number: 79
```

line 79:

```
function create_captcha()
    {
    $vals = array(
        'img_path'   => './captcha/',
        'img_url'    => 'captcha/',
    );
$cap = create_captcha($vals);
    $data = array(
    'captcha_time'  => $cap['time'],
    'ip_address'    => $this->input->ip_address(),
    'word'   => $cap['word']
    );
    $query = $this->db->insert_string('captcha', $data);
    $this->db->query($query); // this line 79
    }
```

Comment: Your create_captcha() function is very confusing, particularly this line:

`$cap = create_captcha($vals);`

You are passing it an array you just created and expect it to return   another array? That doesn't make much sense. As of right now, `$cap` will always be NULL.

Comment: It's all in the error message. That column cannot be NULL, you try to set it to NULL. As it can not set to NULL, you get the error. That simple it is.

Answer (score 6):

You're getting this error because the folder "/captcha" is either not on your server or has the wrong permissions set.

if the image path doesn't exist, or isn't writeable the create_captcha() function returns false, have a look in the captcha helper.

Comment: also I just noticed your function is called create_captcha(), I don't know if that will conflict as the helper function is also called create_captcha. I call mine initiate_captcha() for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

the column `captcha_time` in your `captch`a table cannot be set to null.
you have to sent the time.
as far as i understand: `$cap['time']` is actually null or not set.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you missing install php-gd extention.
suppose your environment is fedora.
yum install php-gd

Answer (score 1):

i can not comment on a answers or vote but the answer from [xds2000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8681275/5149281)
fixed my issue,
on ubuntu machine you need to install it like this

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd && sudo php5enmod gd && sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue! just install gd extension according to your PHP version. I have 5.6 and the following command fixed my issue.

```
1) sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd
2) restart your server
```